# Finding the length of a certain part of a list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to figure out how to find the length of a certain part of a list. For example, my program has a usernames, and passwords in my config file. Is there a way to figure out how many usernames there are? And if so then how?

```
#Also any of the spaces you see between the words are just for reading's sake
#and won't be there in the final program

firsttime:
True

Username:
user1
user2

Password:
pass1
pass2

Key:
key

Theme:
#303030
white
```

Comment: If you have control over the format of the config file then you should consider using a data format like json or yaml, which make this type of structured data interaction much easier.

Comment: just like @Conor said: use `json` for config file and read it using `json` standard module

Comment: thanks for the advice. I don't really know how to use either but ill take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very late to responding to my own post but I made my own parser of sorts which works very well in my opinion.

```
# dictionary.txt can be replaced with any file

def gettext(header, move, count):
    with open('dictionary.txt', 'r') as f:
        f = f.read()
        lines = f.split("\n")

    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if header in line:
            word = []
            for l in range(0, count):
                newindex = i + move
                word.append(lines[newindex+l])

            return "\n".join(word)
```

This works well for any file format like the one I had. The `header` variable is the header you are looking for and then looks for the string then. You can even join together multiple lines together with the `count` variable and the `move` is used to look x lines down to then grab the string.

Answer (score 0):

If we suppose that your configuration lines are stored in a file called `my_conf.cfg`, we can try to code a custom parser like this:

```
with open('(...)/my_conf.cfg') as cf:
    _con_lines = cf.readlines()

configuration = {}
for c_l in _con_lines:
    c_l.strip('\n')
    if not c_l or c_l.startswith('#'):
    
        continue
    if c_l.endswith(':'):
        key = c_l[:-1]
        configuration[key] = []
    else:
        configuration[key].append(c_l)
```

Then the answer to your question is

```
len(configuration['Username'])
```

Comment: configuration[key].append(c_l)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'key' referenced before assignment
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: This may happen if you work with a file different from that in the question, where the first lines are not comments (begging with "#"), nor empty lines, nor keys (ending with colon). Maybe a line with only some blank spaces, and in that case I would replace `if not c_l (...)` with `if not c_l.strip() (...)`.
If it still doesn't work and the config file is exactly the same of the question, other solutions should be explored, such as different and line characters, like `\r` or `\r\n` instead of `\n`.